# Time-synchronized MP3 streaming to web clients

Tags: javascript, html, audio, actionscript, synchronization

There is an hour-long `.mp3` file on the local disk of an HTTP server. About 10 web clients (using recent versions of Chrome or Firefox, with a recent version of Flash installed) start downloading that file. The JavaScript or Flash ActionScript on the web page causes the audio in the `.mp3` file to be played on the speakers of the web client computers. Playback of the audio is started before the file download has completed, and the file is not saved to disk on the web client (so this is streaming).

Each web client user must hear the same audio at about the same time, no matter when he started downloading. (Of course, he will miss earlier parts of the audio.) The maximum allowed time difference is 30 milliseconds, i.e. if user A hears a particular piece of audio from the file, then user B should also hear it no more than 30 milliseconds later. It's not necessary to have low latency, e.g. it's OK to buffer audio for up to 5 seconds (preferably only up to 2 seconds) on the client side, but the actual playback on the speakers should happen in a synchronized way.

Let's suppose that the clocks on the clients and the server go at the same speed for the duration of the playback, but they can be set to very different times. The ServerDate JavaScript library (https://github.com/NodeGuy/ServerDate) or something similar can be used to make the client JavaScript code know about the server time at high accuracy.

It's OK to pre-encode the `.mp3` with any settings (e.g. low, constant bitrate). It's also OK to convert it to another lossy compression format supported by the web clients.

My question is: how can such a system be implemented? What existing technologies (e.g. WebRTC, JW Player, other web players) can be used? What are relevant open source and free software technologies available? Can HTML5 + JavaScript give better synchronization accuracy than a Flash-based player (or does this matter)? Is an implementation already available?

I've found a similar question: [mp3 website player with synchronized playback (not streaming)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8844048/mp3-website-player-with-synchronized-playback-not-streaming) My requirements are stricter than that: the time difference between web clients shouldn't be more than 30 milliseconds. It also doesn't deal with clock synchronization.

Comment: 30ms will be tough to do, but anything under 75 is largely un-noticeable unless the speakers are right next to each other. i've gotten close by using a formula that assumed a post-close() response delay of 10ms, so resp.serverDate+10 gives the latency compensated server time. you also need to deliver a start time relative to that same server clock. then, audio.currentPosition=(serverTime-startTime)/1000; you will need to rinse and repeat as buffering the data will screw that up the first time you set the pos.

Comment: @dandavis: The speakers are in different cities. But it's still important to be synchronized, because there is a reaction speed competition among the users, and the one who hears the audio earlier has an unfair advantage. 100 ms is too much advantage for the best users, 50 ms is borderline much.

Comment: the minimal human reaction time is 140ms, and the different latencies of sending the action back from the client will cause more variation than 30ms due to the speed of light: moscow is 125ms from NYC by light, so maybe you need to track and compare user-relative times in determining who was faster...

Comment: @dandavis: Let's assume that users don't cheat. The JavaScript client can measure the user reaction time, and it can send that local measurement to the server. The distance between client and server doesn't matter. But I'm still looking for ways of synchronized audio playback on web clients. I understand that another way to do it is querying the current (local) media playback position from JavaScript at the time the user presses Enter as a reaction.

Comment: ok, well in php echo the server time right before you die(). the delay from there to the client is usually very minimal as 90%+ of the http delay is waiting for php/apache to answer the phone. once connected, it doesn't take very long to send the data.

Comment: @dandavis: Thank you for the insights. I have many other solutions as well (e.g. the ServerDate library) to synchronize time between the server and the client JavaScript. In this question I'm asking about synchronized audio playback.